# Bash - how to run command based on match/unmatch results from regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, command-line

I am writing a Linux bash function in `~/.bashrc` to do something automatically for me

```
#!/bin/bash
......
......

function cog102start
{
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ibm/cognos/c102_6/cgi-bin
    httpd64start
    DB2START=$(sudo -u db2inst1 /home/db2inst1/sqllib/adm/db2start)

    ________need something here_________
}
```

The output of `DB2START` would contain either

```
SQL1036N DB2START process was successful
```

or

```
SQL1026N The database manager is already active
```

How to test in if statement to decide what to do next?

I am trying to

```
if [ [ $DB2START =~ ^(SQL1036N|SQL1026N)$ ] ]; then dosomething; fi
```

Gives me a syntax error... I don't know what else to try here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
if [[ $DB2START =~ ^(SQL1036N|SQL1026N)$ ]]; then dosomething; fi
```

The `[[` and `]]` are single tokens; no space is allowed in between.

Answer (score 2):

```
if [ [ $DB2START =~ ^(SQL1036N|SQL1026N)$ ] ]; then dosomething; fi
    ^                                      ^
     \                                    /
      --- no space here        or here ---
```